# Cómo evitar la carga de datos vacíos en mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo hecho un formulario sencillo en php que carga información (gastos) en una base de datos mysql.

El formulario es muy básico. Son campos que se cargan mediante el método post que hace referencia a un archivo "envio-formulario.php".

Cómo hago para evitar que se ejecute la acción cuando ingreso a la URL envio-formulario.php? Si no prevengo ese hecho se pueden cargar datos vacíos.

Answer (score 1):

Yo usaría en tu formulario "envio-formulario.php" la función isset. Esta funcion determina si una variable está definida y no es NULL.

Puedes encontrar toda la información en la página oficial de [php](http://php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php), aunque aquí te dejo un pequeño ejemplo de como usarlo

**Página del formulario**

```
<form action='envio-formulario.php' method='post'> <!--también puede ser get,dependiendo tus necesidades-->
<input type='text' name='nombre>
<input type='submit' value='Enviar'>
</form>
```

**envio-formulario.php**

```
if (isset($_POST['nombre'])){
......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

te recomendaría usar javascript para la validación ya que lo que necesitas es que no avance a la página siguiente si esta mal el formulario o en defecto, vació, pues bien un formulario se comprende con:

```
<form action='pagina.php' method='post'> <!--también puede ser get,dependiendo tus necesidades-->
<input type='text' name='nombre' required><!--el required, no deja enviar el formulario si esta vacio ¡USALO!  -->
<input type='submit' value='Enviar'>
</form>
```

la solución es el atributo required de la etiqueta input,recuerda que esto es en el HTML, en la etiqueta body (disculpa si estoy siendo muy específico)

Comment: Validar solo en el frontend no va a ayudar mucho a evitar que los campos se envíen vacios por usuarios que conozcan herramientas básicas de depuración (y modificación) de frontend, la validación debe hacerse también en backend (php en este caso)

Comment: muy bien...
$var = 0;

// Se evalúa a true ya que $var está vacia
if (empty($var)) {
    echo '$var es o bien 0, vacía, o no se encuentra definida en absoluto';
}
Puedes validar con esa sencilla condición si lo que quieres es que no avance y válide  en ese mismo instante, tendras que enviar una petición al servidor, con ajax (en mi caso yo uso ) jquery

Comment: Suscribo lo comentado por @Shaz y añado, por otra parte, la pregunta está relacionada directamente con `php`/`mysql`, lógicamente, la validación con `javascript`es una opción, pero no responde a la pregunta inicial: _¿Cómo hago para evitar que se ejecute la acción cuando ingreso a la URL envio-formulario.php?_

Comment: *Lo que se busca*  "evitar que se ejecute la acción cuando ingreso a la URL envio-formulario.php"
así que lo más conveniente sería hacer una petición al servidor enviando los campos para verificar si son correctos en php, y retornar una respuesta, para saber si son  o no correctos